# Normed space always vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Why the definition of a normed space always includes that it is a vector space and not just a set with a norm like as with metric spaces?
So are there normed spaces (only set+norm) that are not vector spaces or is it necessary to have objects like vectors to define a norm?

Comment: A norm operates on the vector space operation, namely the triangle inequality operates on the sum of vector and the scaling operates, well, on the vector scaling. So, yes, norms only make sense on vector spaces (they already lack sense on subsets of vector subspaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of a norm already assumes the set is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If we don't have addition and scalar multiplication then the axioms $||x+y||\leq ||x||+||y||$ and $||\alpha\cdot x||=|\alpha|\cdot ||x||$ make no sense.

You should not confuse between normed spaces and metric spaces. These are two different terms. The relation is that a norm defines a metric on the vector space by $d(x,y)=||x-y||$, but that's it. There are lots of other metrics as well. (and not just on vector spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is needed to give sense to addition of points belonging to such sets. Otherwise expressions like $\|x + y\|$, where $x\in (E,\|\cdot\|)$ and $y\in(E,\|\cdot\|)$, would not have any meaning and the normed space definition would be unsatisfactory.

More precisely, one has the following definition of normed space.

Let $E$ be a vector space. We say the function $\|\cdot\|:E\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a norm if and only if the following relations hold:

- $\|x\| = 0$ iff $x = 0$,
- $\|\lambda x\| = |\lambda|\|x\|$, and
- $\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$

As you can notice, the very first notion of norm requires the structure of vector space.